# encode a text which contains hex string into utf-8

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm struggling to encode this hex string: `=D8=A8=D8=A7 <br /> =D8=B3=D9=84=D8=A7=D9=85 hello =D9=88 =D8=A7=D8=AD=D8=AA=D8=B1=D8=A7= =D9=85` into proper format which must be **utf-8** and must be displayed as :

> با 
>  سلام hello و احترا= م

What I've tried so far is that at first step I've tried to decode hex string with decode function but since there are invalid digit in my hex string (`=`) it throws error:

```
select decode(content, 'hex') from attachments
```

> ERROR:  invalid hexadecimal digit: "="

I also tried to directly convert it to utf-8 but nothing has changed in output:

```
select convert_from(content::bytea, 'utf-8') from attachments
```

> `=D8=A8=D8=A7 <br /> =D8=B3=D9=84=D8=A7=D9=85 hello =D9=88 =D8=A7=D8=AD=D8=AA=D8=B1=D8=A7= =D9=85`

Comment: The data you are looking at is encoded as quoted-printable. Blindly converting = followed by hex digits will *almost* decode it correctly, but you also need to be aware that `=` at end of line is an escape.

Comment: @tripleee thank you for clarification. Could you please show me how to convert `quoted-printable`? The fact of the matter is that there are quite a lot of invalid hexadecimals in my string. forexample `<div>`, `hello`, `<br />`..... I updated my question.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that in Postgres.

Comment: Right you are! I'm working on it, but it's really not that simple

Comment: @tripleee `but you also need to be aware that = at end of line is an escape` Now I'm facing with random `=` at the end of random lines. Could you please explain more what is this character? Maybe I could handle it if i know.

Comment: Quoted-printable is defined in [RFC 2045](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-6.7); see also [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). A line-final `=` simply escapes the newline, meaning the sequence `=` (newline)  should simply be discarded when decoding.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
select convert(decode(replace(replace(content,'=',''),' ','20'), 'hex'),'UTF8') from attachments
```

or

```
select convert_from(decode(replace(replace(content,'=',''),' ','20'), 'hex')::bytea, 'utf-8') from attachments
```

Comment: much appreciated, its close to answer, but problem is, it still removes space character `select convert_from(decode(replace('=D8=A8=D8=A7 =D8=B3=D9=84=D8=A7=D9=85 =D9=88 =D8=A7=D8=AD=D8=AA=D8=B1=D8=A7= =D9=85','=',' '), 'hex')::bytea, 'utf-8') from attachments`

Comment: Yes thank you. But it could be better to use an approach that automatically detect and convert hex parts of string. By your proposed approach I need to replace every single remaining invalid hex characters like '>', '/', '<', 'P', 'I', etc....

Comment: Thank you, I had to update my question. Your answer was correct before I update my question. I'm sorry because I didn't mentioned to it at first place.